# Contextual meaning of "run out of"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

This is from CSI NY. Two investigators are examining a victim's body.

> Joe: Well, I almost **ran out of** here.  Any idea who she is?
>
> Mic: No. Definitely doesn't work in the lab.

Comment: This'll need more context before the meaning can be identified.  Why can't it just mean what it looks like (Joe almost ran out of the place)?

Comment: Without more context, I think this is "Not a real question".

Comment: ...perhaps it's just a mistranscription for **I almost ran over her**. Admittedly he'd be more likely to say *almost tripped over her*, but we're clutching at straws here...

Comment: I wonder if it was so gruesome the person nearly ran away?

Answer (score 2):

From the context given, it appears  intended to be parsed as "ran" (verb, past tense of "run": to move at a very fast pace) "out of here" (away from the current location).

(Not as in "ran out of" (ended up with no items left of) "here" (the current location), which clearly doesn't make any sense.)

One presumes that Joe was very surprised and scared upon discovering the victim's body in the lab, and almost ran away because he was so frightened.

Comment: +1, finding the audio would remove all doubt - or if Cheryl could explain where the stress (pause) was.

Comment: Given that Joe is a CSI NY "investigator", it's unlikely he'd be freaked out by finding a body anywhere.